# Is there a comma after an adjective that is before a quote?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Which punctuation, if any, is correct:

1. He replied with a dismissive "No, I'm not interested."
2. He replied with a dismissive, "No, I'm not interested."

If there is an unlisted option that is more correct than the two above, what would it be?